# How to optimize user experience on existing platform?

Tags: website-design, web-app, mobile-web, web

If you have a working website, is there a way to tell if parts of it are bad or good?

Let's take my hobby project for example which is a [cryptocurrency live data platform](https://bitculator.com/), I develop this as a hobby project whenever I have spare time.

I would like to know if my website has a good user experience, I'm not getting much traffic so I'm in doubt that it is any good, I personally think it is amazing but it does not reflect on the traffic.

How do I figure this stuff out, do I just hire a person from Fiverr, or is there any way for me to ensure it is good, any tools or similar people use to test user experience?

Comment: What does it mean "not getting much traffic"? If you don't get many visitors, that is a marketing/SEO issue. Otherwise use an analytics tool to see where people get stuck, investigate that and describe a detailed UX problem here. For now I vote to close the question as being a request for a site review. See also the [Help Center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help) if you need help formulating a question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like an attempt to get a backlink to their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are a few possible answers to your question... let me hazard a few thoughts.

Part of the problem might be the findability of your site. Do people know it exists? If not, you might need to implement a [keyword and/or SEO strategy](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-strategic-insights-tactical-advice/383325/) to get your site placement higher in searches. You could also use a [social media campaign](https://blog.aspiration.marketing/en/social-media-ideas-to-try) to get your site out there to more people. But if it is a hobby site that might not really matter to you so much.

As for the site itself, you may want to run it through some online optimization tools, such as [Google Optimize](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/optimize/) (now part of a marketing suite, but still with a free trial), [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/), [HotJar](https://www.hotjar.com/) and/or [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) (which may require some additions and modifications to your site to best leverage), or any of [a number of other available tools](https://bloggingwizard.com/website-optimization-tools/) out there.

If you want to actually test your site with users, there are many, many ways to run usability tests of all sorts on your site, in person or remote. [Optimal Workshop](https://www.optimalworkshop.com/) is a great set of tools, has a free trial, and can test many things about your site organization and your users' paths through it. You can use remote, unmoderated test platforms to set up tests, get participants, run your tests, and collect results using [a testing platform](https://www.usertesting.com/). There are also any number of low-cost or free ways to interact with your users and get insights - call them up and [interview them](https://uxdesign.cc/cognitive-interviews-for-user-research-59d2b3c568fc) about it; send out [a survey](https://www.google.com/forms/about/); Get a Zoom/GoToMeeting/Teams/whatever video chat platform you like call going and do a [usability test](https://www.userinterviews.com/blog/usability-testing-best-practices) to see how they work through the use cases on your site. Run a [card-sort](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html) with some to see if things are organized well.

These are just a few thoughts - try some out, see what works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, i will definitely look into your links

Answer (score 2):

If we remove marketing and advertising from the equation, the law of user experience optimization is very clear:

Research, research, and research again.

I highly recommend that you segment your target audience into relevant groups. Ask the right questions to understand how users interact with your website and for what purpose. Once you have insights, you can start designing. And of course, the most important step in my opinion is:

Usability testing.

Once your product is live or prototyped, let your users test it out and see where they click, how easy it is to navigate your information architecture, and whether the buttons are clear.

user experience is a whole world of small innovations and large methodologies. I recommend consulting with a user experience specialist or reading a bit about the methodology and rationale of ux.

good luck !

Comment: Thanks, ill take that into consideration

Answer (score 1):

In the real world, it's not the best products that sell well, it's the best *promoted* products.
Many companies spend more money on advertising than they do on developing and producing their products.

Total traffic is a good measure of the *popularity*, not of the *quality* of a web site.
(Compare the top American TV programs, most of which have very poor intellectual quality, with the excellent but seldom watched PBS dramas, some of which are imported from your Denmark.)

A simple but much better measure for your site would be how many users *return* to use it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that kinda made me think I should do more to get it out there